# How do I configure PHP to run locally?

Tags: windows, php, localhost, iis

I have attempted to configure my system to run a PHP server.

I'm running Windows 10, and using IIS.

I've gone through the Windows Features and turned on the Web Management Tools under the Internet Information Services -

[image]

I have gone to `LocalHost` and that works fine : 
[image]

I have downloaded and tried installing PHP 5.6.0 with the Web Platform Installer - 
[image]

For some reason when I try to install this, though I get an error on one of the files that is automatically added when I selected `PHP 5.6.0` to install - the PHP Manager for IIS:

[image]
[image]

When I went to download and install the file manually, it tells me this -

[image]

I have created the bare-bones PHP file like it suggested [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2819022) :

```
<?
    phpinfo();
?>
```

I have saved this file to the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` directory :

[image]

However, when I go to LocalHost/Info.php all I get is this -

[image]

I've tried [manually](http://windows.php.net/download/) [installing](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php) PHP and configuring the `.ini` file and I'vet tried manually adding the `PHP_via_FastCGI`Module Mapping to the IIS Handler Mappings -

[image]

In order to make certain the PHP file was actually being looked at, I've added plain text to it, and that appears fine -

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Why is the `phpinfo()` command not coming through?

Comment: It may be that the short tag <? is not supported. Try changing the file to start with <?php as the first line?

Comment: @Keny yeah... that did it... forget my life... thanks. If you care to put that in the form of an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that the short tag `<?` is not supported. Try changing the file to start with `<?php` as the first line?

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely because the PHP file is not being parsed by IIS for some reason. It could be that the `info.php` file itself is not plain text or corrupted in some way. Remember when you program you need to us a plain-text editor; not something that adds extra stuff like Word and such.

Typically when a blank/white screen comes up in PHP it means an error has occurred so you should check your IIS logs or adjust the `php.ini` to display errors in the web browser. Just look for `display_errors` in your `php.ini` and set that to `display_errors=1`

But in all honesty, unless you really need PHP to run via IIS, you are far better off using [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) which are canned versions of a Windows version of a LAMP stack—Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP—but for Windows systems. These prepackaged development environments save you tons of headaches and are widely supported in the PHP development community.

If you go down the route to install PHP from source on your own on an system you basically are going to be spending far too much time dealing with system idiosyncrasies than actually getting PHP development done. Always opt for a pre-packaged *AMP stack over messing with your core OS.

Comment: The reason I *have* to use IIS is because I do not know if there are any alternatives. I tried XAMPP but it didn't work - when I tried to start the Apache server it just failed.

Comment: That's fine - so I just remove IIS and run XAMPP... and then I can just launch a .php file and everything will be hunky dory?

Comment: Okay; following your instructions I disabled IIS and went with XAMPP. When I go to LocalHost it takes me to the same IIS page but with the XAMPP logo. I can confirm it's working (I think anyway) since when I tried to go to my info.php file it failed with a 404.

However, when I moved the file to the location it should be and again tried to run it, same deal - blank screen.